# c++ integer division

Tags: c++, sdl

Say I've got

```
SDL_Rect rect;
rect.x = 5; // rect.x is of type "Uint16"
int y = 11;
```

and I want to perform the operation `rect.x/y`.

I want to get the result as a floating point number and then round up to the nearest `int`.

Something like this:

```
float result = rect.x/y;
int rounded = ceil(result);
```

How should I do this?

Comment: Have you tried that? What does it give you?

Comment: trial and error before you stackoverflow, please?

Comment: @chris: Depending on the value of "rect.x", sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't (I get segmentation fault due to uninitialised value)

Comment: A segfault due to uninitialised value doesn't sound like it has anything to do with division or `ceil`.  Probably an invalid pointer use somewhere else in the program.

Comment: @aschepler, as it turns out, you were right!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cast either `rect.x` or `y` to float, and then do the division. This will force the entire division operation to take place in floating point.

```
float result = rect.x/(float)y;
int rounded = ceil(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast your variables.

```
float result = (float)rect.x / (float)y;
int rounded = ceil(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without any floating point types.  If `x` and `y` are positive integers, then x divided by y, rounded up is `(x+y-1)/y`.